# Grid lines are overlapping in an interchanged fashion

Tags: html, css

I have a grid drawn on four corners using four `span` elements. Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/P5OK6qFnmL5lH69LMn78?p=preview).

[image]

Now, i like the vertical bars to be drawn on top of the horizontal bars. Like, yellow bar must be drawn above the black and green bar by which i mean the grid intersecting regions must be in yellow. Similarly brown bar must be above green bar.

How can i achieve it?

Comment: Just set different `z-index` or [reorder](https://plnkr.co/edit/O4IVYMsUhKXiX4wSIZJ3?p=preview) the elements in the html.

Comment: it doesn't move them up the top line!!!

Comment: If you can make the question clearer I'm sure someone will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply adding

```
.left, .right{
    z-index:1;
}
```

To your code should do the trick

Comment: it moves the vertical lines above the black bottom line.. but they are still below the top green line

Comment: I didn't read this in your question - the issue is you have position:absolute set on the other elements, but not on 'top' class. Setting this position:absolute also will resolve this